Is There a Way to Place Dropdown Options Inside the Option Selection Menu?
Particularly for my specific situation, using the dcc.Dropdown works perfectly. The only problem is that in many situations, the user might select multiple options, which will look really ugly visually.
Is there a way to make the dropdown like this?
I have already thought about creating a menu that opens with options that can be selected as a checklist, but that would be more complex to code because I want to allow the user to search for the option they want just like in the standard dcc.Dropdown

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You just need to add Checklist inside of Dropdown.
In my case I used dbc.DropdownMenu and dbc.Checklist
app.layout = html.Div(
    [dbc.DropdownMenu(
            [dbc.Checklist(
            options=[{'label':x,'value':x} for x in df.sort_values('Hospital')['Hospital'].unique()],
            value=[],
                inline=True,
            id="checklist-input",
        ),
            ],
            label="Menu",
        ),
        html.Div(id="item-clicks", className="mt-3"),
    ]
)


